# how to close a user defined Thread with close (X) icon of the scren in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I use the following code to create a user-defined Java Thread and perform some action continuously. then I want to destroy this Thread while the user wants to close the windows and clicks on (X) icon of the window.

```
class Simple
{   
    Threa thread;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {    
        thread = new Thread(new MyThreadClass(this));
        thread.start();
    }
//code
}//Simple

class MedicalStoreSalesPageControllerThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Action which is continuously performed
    }
}//MedicalStoreSalesPageControllerThread
```

I'm talking about (X) sign at top right corner of window

[image: I'm talking about (X) sign at top right corner of window]

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Catching events when the window closes, or stopping the thread? You're run method should check to see if it needs to keep running then when the window is closed you change the threads condition.

Comment: See my example: primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {event.consume(); ...

Comment: Your answer was awesome, It did work for me. Thanks @anko

Answer (score -1):

I created a small exmaple how you could do it.

Main Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        // Get the controller instance
        Controller controller = loader.getController();

        // Prevent closing when user clicks on the (X) sign at top right corner of window:
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            event.consume();
            controller.closeApp();
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    private MyTask myTask;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        myTask = new MyTask();
        new Thread(myTask).start();
    }

    void closeApp() {
        // Cancel task and close
        if (myTask.cancel())
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

MyTask Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;

class MyTask extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("running");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void cancelled() {
        System.out.println("stopped");
    }
}
```

Comment: This exits the application. This doesn't do anything to stop the thread, aside for the fact the application exits.

Comment: Not explicitly, you want to take care of your call method. https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html  In their examples they check for 'isCancelled to stop doing work, and finishing the call method. Everything should work for you without the 'System.exit' as javafx will exit when all of the windows are closed. Also, you should explain your answer for the OP a bit.

Comment: again playing guessing games ;) It's impossible to write a good answer to a bad question ..

Comment: When the user clicks the close button he wants to do something (stop some thread) before the app closes. Pretty obv for me.

Comment: It can't be more simplified, (When the user clicks the close button he wants to do something (stop some thread) before the app closes). @kleopatra